# How can I split a SQL table into multiple based on columns which have the same elements?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgis

At the moment I have one large SQL table. Let's say it looks like this:

```
Table: allData
County Census Tract Population Name
001    xxxxxx       4328       County1
001    yyyyyy       4729       County1
002    zzzzzz       5629       County2
003    aaaaaa       3947       County3
```

What I want is an individual table for each county. So I would have:

```
Table: County1
County Census Tract Population Name
001    xxxxxx       4328       County1
001    yyyyyy       4729       County1

Table: County2
County Census Tract Population Name
002    zzzzzz       5629       County2

Table: County3
County Census Tract Population Name
003    aaaaaa       3947       County3
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want this? Why not just add a condition on the country to your `where` clauses?

Comment: That indeed sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: What's the use case? Why would you like to do such a thing? It would just make your life difficult. Seriously.

Comment: I need a unique file for each county.

Comment: If you're using `COPY` to create the files, you can give it a query rather than a table name. That way you can export to any number of files.

Comment: A table is not "a file". Again: why do you think you need that in separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case requires a separate table for each County you can use the following SQL to generate `create table` statements

```
select 'create table '+Name+' as select * from allData where name = '''+Name+''';'
  from allData
 group by name
```

This SQL will generate `insert` statements

```
select 'insert into '+Name+' select * from allData where name = '''+Name+''';'
  from allData
 group by name
```

You can run each of these above and copy paste the result into your SQL client to create and populate the tables

If you need to specify schema names add it right before `Name` like

```
select 'create table <schema.>'+Name+' as select * from allData where name = '''+Name+''';'
```

I have used the following SQL to test the same

```
with allData as (    
select '001' County,    'xxxxxx' Census_Tract,       4328 Population,      'County1' Name union all
select '001',    'yyyyyy',       4729,       'County1' union all
select '002',    'zzzzzz',       5629,       'County2' union all
select '003',    'aaaaaa',       3947,       'County3' )
select 'create table '+Name+' as select * from allData where name = '''+Name+''';'
group by name;

with allData as (    
select '001' County,    'xxxxxx' Census_Tract,       4328 Population,      'County1' Name union all
select '001',    'yyyyyy',       4729,       'County1' union all
select '002',    'zzzzzz',       5629,       'County2' union all
select '003',    'aaaaaa',       3947,       'County3' )
select 'insert into '+Name+' select * from allData where name = '''+Name+''';'
from allData
group by name;
```